# How to refetch api data on client side in next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I need to reload the data from api once state changed. Is is possible to fetch data again with getInitialProps on client side?

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Comment: Try fetch your data using `componentDidMount` react lifecycle when your state updates

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you fetch the data on the componentDidMount?

```
componentDidMount() {
  yourAPI.fetch().then((pFetchData) => {
    this.setState({data: pFetchData});
  });
}
```

In practice, componentDidMount is the best place to put calls to fetch data, for two reasons:

1. Using DidMount makes it clear that data won't be loaded until after
   the initial render. This reminds you to set up initial state
   properly, so you don't end up with undefined state that causes
   errors.
2. If you ever need to render your app on the server
   (SSR/isomorphic/other buzzwords), componentWillMount will actually be
   called twice “ once on the server, and again on the client “ which is
   probably not what you want. Putting the data loading code in
   componentDidMount will ensure that data is only fetched from the
   client.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1177776/Where-to-Fetch-Data-componentWillMount-vs-componen

Hope it helps :)